# Find the general solution of $\cos(x)-\cos(2x)=\sin(3x)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Problem:

> Find the general solution of $$\cos(x)-\cos(2x)=\sin(3x)$$

I tried attempting this by using the formula$$\cos C-\cos D=-2\sin(\dfrac{C+D}{2})\sin(\dfrac{C-D}{2})$$

Thus, $$-2\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{3x}{2}\right)=\sin 3x$$
$$\Rightarrow -2\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{3x}{2}\right)-\sin 3x=0$$

Unfortunately, I couldn't get further with this problem. Any help  with this would be truly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: On the right hand side, use formula sin2x = 2 sinx cosx.

Comment: But you can turn sin3x into sin(x+2x) and then use addition then double angle.

Comment: You were on the good way. Continue with $\sin(3x)=2\sin(\frac {3x}2)\cos(\frac{3x}2)$

Comment: Put x = 3t/2, you get sin3t = 2 sin(3t/2) cos(3t/2).

Comment: Change $\sin(t)$ to some $\cos(t+??)$ or vice-versa. By the way, you are very welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& -2 \, \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \, \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = \sin(3x) \\
& \sin(3x) = 2 \, \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \, \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \\
& -2 \, \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \, \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = 2 \, \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \, \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \\
& \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \, \left(-2 \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - 2 \, \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \right) = 0 \\
& \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = 0  \quad  \text{or} \quad \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) 
\end{align}

Comment: sin(2x)=2sinx.cosx  so  sin(3x)=2sin(3x/2).cos(3x/2)

Comment: sin(a)=cos(90-a)   put   a=x/2  : sin(x/2) = cos(90-x/2) = cos(3 x/2)

Comment: solve cos(90-x/2)=cos(3x/2)

Answer (score 2):

1. Expand the trig functions $$ \cos(x)+1-2 \cos^2(x) = 4 \sin(x) \cos^2(x)-\sin(x)$$
2. Use the [tangent half angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) $t=\tan(x/2)$, $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin(x) = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2}$ $$ \frac{2 t^2 (3-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2} = \frac{2 t (3 t^4-10 t^2+3)}{(1+t^2)^3}$$
3. Collect terms $$\frac{2 t (t+1) (t^2-3) (t^2+2t-1)}{(1+t^2)^3} = 0$$
4. Solve for $t$ $$\begin{align} t&=0\\t&=-1\\t&=\sqrt{3}\\t&=-\sqrt{3}\\t&=\sqrt{2}-1\\t&=-\sqrt{2}-1 \end{align}$$
5. Solve for $x=2 \arctan(t)$ $$\begin{align}
   x&=0\\
   x&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\\
   x&=\frac{2\pi}{3}\\
   x&=-\frac{2\pi}{3}\\
   x&=\frac{\pi}{4}\\
   x&=-\frac{3\pi}{4}
   \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use $$\cos(2x)=2\cos(x)^2-1$$ and $$\sin(3x)=3\cos(x)^2\sin(x)-\sin(x)^3$$
then you will get $$\cos \left( x \right) -2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+
1-4\,\sin \left( x \right)  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}
+\sin \left( x \right) 
=0$$
now use tan half-angle substitution

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
−2 \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \, \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)−\sin 3x &=0 \\
−2 \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \, \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)-2 \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \, \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) &=0 \\
\sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) =0 \quad \text{or} \quad \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) &=0 \\
\sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = \sin(0) \quad \text{or} \quad \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) &= \cos\left(\frac{π-x}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: the last, cos equation, becomes $3x/2=\pm(\pi/2-x/2)+2k\pi$